# How to change the stateindex of a rootnode in Virtual Treeview?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a ImageList assigned in Stateimages of a Virtual Treeview.
How can I change the stateindex of a root node? I can't find anything.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `OnGetImageIndex` event. There you can set the `var ImageIndex` to the index of your image in the `ImageList`.

Should you need to only apply to root nodes, you can check if the nodes `parent = nil`.

From the help:

> 10.1.2.104 TBaseVirtualTree.OnGetImageIndex Event
>
> property OnGetImageIndex: TVTGetImageEvent; Description
>
> This event is triggered whenever the tree needs the index of an image,
>   be it the normal, the selected or the state image. The  event  should 
>   be  as  fast  as  possible  because  it  is  at  times  frequently 
>   called  when  the  layout  of  the  node  must  be determined, e.g.
>   while doing draw selection with the mouse or painting the tree. Kind
>   determines which image is needed and  Column  determines  for  which
>   column  of  the  node  the  image  is  needed.  This  value  can  be 
>   -1  to  indicate  there  is  no column used. The parameter Ghosted can be set  to  true  to  blend the  image  50% against the  tree 
>   background and can be used  for  instance  in  explorer  trees  to 
>   mark hidden  file  system  objects.  Additionally  nodes  are  also 
>   drawn  with a  ghosted icon  if  the are part of a cut set during a
>   pending cut-to-clipboard operation. In  this case changing the ghosted
>   parameter has no effect. Notes Blending nodes can be switched by using
>   toUseBlendImages in TreeOptions.PaintOptions. Class

Comment: You need to use the `Kind` property (I think) that is passed with the delegate.

Comment: +1, yup, there's the `Kind` parameter in the `OnGetImageIndex` event. When this event is fired and the `Kind` parameter is `ikState` then return the `ImageIndex` of your `Stateimages` image list.